# Adverbial phrase or Adjectival phrase?

Tags: prepositional-phrases, adverbial-phrases, adjectivals

I was reading a text on archaeology came across with:

> Often these objects lie **buried in the ground**, so our image of the archaeologist is of a scientist who is always digging.

I think **buried in the ground** is a adjectival phrase. But I guess the author tries to make point of objects that lied beneath the earth. Could I have your comments ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I apologize for raising the tiresome adverbial controversy again; but I think that the traditional analysis of this phrase presented in BobRodes' answer is wrong on just about every point.

1. The head of this phrase is *buried*, a 'past/passive participle'. The two roles played simultaneously by participles of this sort are verb and adjective, not verb and adverb.
2. It's hard to measure how verbish any given participle is; but I'd say this one is externally almost completely deverbal (I'll come back to that *externally* later). BobRodes offers a paraphrase "Often these objects are buried in the ground" and suggests that this implies a passivization of the action of burying. I accept the paraphrase wholeheartedly; but I reject the implication.

   A passive reading implies a generic present reading, "These things are repeatedly buried in the ground at present"; and that, in turn, imputes dynamicity and indeed agency to the repeated event: "People at present frequently bury these things in the ground". (I suppose we could explain away the present tense by arguing that these things *have been buried*, but I think this goes beyond what is implied here: we have no way of telling whether 'these things' are a deliberately buried hoard of hacksilver or potsherds which have sunk by their own weight into the muck at the bottom of dried-up riverbed.)

   But there's no action here, performed either by or upon *these things*. In "these objects are buried", *are* is not a passive auxiliary but an ordinary copula, and we are dealing not with a recurrent event but with a widespread current *state*: the location of these things.
3. I find it impossible to conceive how this state, this location, can be understood to 'modify' the verb *lie* any more than it 'modifies' the verb *BE* in the paraphrase. Syntactically, of course, the phrase is a *dependent* of the verb *lie*. But so is everything else in the sentence except *lie* itself; and I don't suppose anybody would argue that *these things* 'modifies' *lie*. **Dependent ≠ modifier**.

   As it is used here, *lie* itself is stative; we're not talking about *these things* performing an action. We cannot paraphrase what is said with *these things **lie down** buried in the ground*, much less that they *lie down 'buriedly' in the ground* or *buried-in-the-groundly*.

   To my mind, indeed, *lie* here is very little more than that same ordinary copula; it's just accreted a sort of postural patina. And the copula, notoriously, is a syntactic device for linking a state or quality or identity to  . . .
4. . . . the *subject*. Whatever their syntactic role, *buried* and *in the ground* are locations attributed to *these things* (as is the recumbent posture signified by the semantic component of *lie*).

   They're adjectivals.

   Specifically, they're adjectival predicate complements attributed to the subject, *these things*.
5. "But wait!" I hear you cry. "Perhaps ... maybe ... there's a remote possibility that *buried* is as you say an adjective; but *in the ground* is beyond question a preposition phrase modifying *buried*. And what modifies an adjective is an *adverb*. Ha! Put *that* in your modernist not-a-pipe and smoke it!"

   No. I freely concede that *in the ground* is a dependent of *buried*; but again, dependent **≠** modifier. Remember that throwaway remark I made about *buried* being "externally almost completely deverbal"? Outside the phrase, *buried* acts as an adjectival; *within* the phrase, however, it can (and here does) act as a verb. (That's why it's called a 'participle': because it 'participates' in multiple roles.)

   Among other verbish roles a participle can participate in is taking the arguments of a verb; and one of the arguments of the verb *bury* is a locative preposition phrase: *Who's buried **in Grant's tomb**?* *Bury me **beneath the willow***. Once more, that PP doesn't 'modify' the verb: it's not a property of  the action, it's the goal of the action, and when the action is perfected it designates the location of the body. It's a property of the patient—of the object when the verb is cast in the active voice, of the subject when the verb is cast in the passive voice.

   *In the ground* is an adjectival predicate complement imputed to the subject.

   And what's the subject of the passive participle *buried*?

   *These things.*

QED

Comment: Thanks, As I understood form your answer, we have : " these objects buried in the ground lie " . It sounds odd ? Why the author didn't use a simple structure ?

Comment: @Cardinal It's just as complicated wherever you put *buried in the ground*. And *lie*,as I said, is a copula; it demands a complement.

Comment: @StoneyB This is very interesting, and you have clearly given it a great deal more thought than I have.  I'll restrict my responses to 2 and 3.  The use of present tense in the sentence does indeed undermine the position that it's passive voice, since the burying takes place at another time.  (On the other hand, if something is buried, something buried it, and whether it was a human hand or simple gravity or some cataclysm doesn't strike me as a relevant distinction.  Nevertheless, on second look that does appear to go beyond what's implied.)  ...

Comment: @BobRodes Hmm ... I think to say that the adjective must imply agency because it derives from an agentive verb is an instance of the etymological fallacy. What, for instance, is the agent of *The answer is buried in the depths of time"?

Comment: ... As for 3, I don't quite understand your analysis, either.  How is it different from, say, "I stood buried up to the knees in cement" or "I fell sideways into the water?"  Do you analyze these sentences in the same way?  It seems there is a whole class of similar stuff.

Comment: @BobRodes Well, I take *stand* to be a stative (after all, they're practically the same word!) like *lie*, so that sentence works the same as OP's. *Fall*, however, is eventive, and it seems to me that *sideways* and *into the water* describe the path of motion. So I would take those to be more like adverbials than adjectivals, although the subject is clearly involved: *sideways* speaks of the subject's orientation to the path, and you do end up **in** the water even if you're not located **into** it. Great Mother English don't make it easy.

Comment: @StoneyB to your next to last, I wouldn't go so far as to say that it *must* imply agency either.  Your "depths of time" example is a very good one to  show how tenuous the link can be.  I misunderstood your examples, getting the idea you were saying that the "hoard" example was relevant as to agency and the "potsherd" one wasn't.  Now I think you're saying that the sentence simply states that they are buried, rather than not buried, without caring how.  So it makes sense to call buried an adjective.  I'm going to change my mind and agree with you, as that's the simpler analysis.

Comment: @StoneyB I'm beginning to feel like I'm back in German class, looking at whether to use Accusative or Dative case with a dual preposition.  :)  I'm not sure that I think the distinction you're drawing here is a real one.  I would say *sideways* is an adverb whether one is standing sideways or falling sideways, and an adjective when casting a sideways glance.

Comment: @BobRodes Oh, I agree. My point was only that syntax is just as fuzzy around the edges as semantics: *sideways* illuminates *fall* directly, but there's some spill onto *you*.

Comment: @StoneyB Oh, all right.  Anyway, interesting discussion.  Thanks for your insights.

Answer (score 2):

This is an interesting phrase, which you can actually analyze in two different ways.

First, *buried in the ground* is an adverbial phrase.  It modifies the verb *lie* (how do the objects lie?), not the noun *objects*. (Adjectives modify nouns, adverbs modify everything else.)

Next, suppose we change the sentence to this:

> Often, these objects are buried in the ground...

In this case, *are buried* is a verb in the passive voice, and *in the ground* is an adverbial phrase modifying *buried*.  As you can see, this doesn't change the meaning of the sentence much at all, so one could also argue that *lie* is used as an alternative auxiliary verb (an alternative to *are*) for the passive voice.

The first analysis is simpler, but the second one is interesting, as it points out that *buried* is used in much the same way that verbs are used in the passive voice--in the passive voice, the subject receives the action rather than performing it.  The first analysis emphasizes the fact that the subject ("these objects") performs the action of lying, whereas the second analysis emphasizes the fact that the subject receives the action of being buried.

Comment: +1 Good answer. I disagree with almost everything in it, but it's still a good answer.